# Haskell Function not loading

Tags: haskell

I have started haskell two day ago using learn you a haskell, but struck in the second chapter.

I saved a function as `baby.hs`(no `.txt`, I checked in info) and according to the book, the function I wrote is `doubleMe x = x + x`. I saved it in documents folder. (also i navigated to that place using ls and cd).

Then I typed the command `ghci>:l baby` , there is an error which says..

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, interpreted )  
baby.hs:1:7: parse error on input ‘\’ Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Forget to mention, I have macbook with os x el capitan. If I use `cat baby.hs`, I get the following:

```
Mayanks-MBP:Documents mayank$ cat baby.hs
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf460 {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;} {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;} \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0 \pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx623‌​6\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0 \f0\fs24 \cf0 doubleMe x = x + x}
Mayanks-MBP:Documents mayank$
```

Comment: Everything looks fine... try `cat baby.hs` (or `more baby.hs` on Win) from the shell to double check the content is the intended one.

Comment: It shows this-                                                                                         Mayanks-MBP:Documents mayank$ cat baby.hs
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf460
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 doubleMe x = x + x}Mayanks-MBP:Documents mayank$

Comment: You used some word processor to produce the .hs file. You can't use that, you need a plain text editor. (It might be possible to coerce a word processor into producing a plain text file, but for programming a good text editor is more approriate.)

Comment: Always [edit] additional information in the question, @MayankGupta. That way, users don't have to scan all comments. Also, comments don't have a edit history, and can be deleted at (almost) any time.

Comment: the usual workaround is to look for "save as" and then select ".txt" but replace the extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a word processor (WordPad, Microsoft Word, etc.), which saves your file in RTF format. However, Haskell source code must be in a plain text format.  I'm not familiar with Mac OS X, but there is probably a `vi`, `nano` or another console editor on your system already. Note that you should get a proper editor rather soon.

Comment: BTW: I think Atom is a good choice for beginners nowadays - it seems to have a good Haskell experience - personally I would use emacs ;) - of course *TextEdit* **is** capable of saving plain text files - you just have to tell it to ;)

Comment: see here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17433/can-textedit-save-as-plain-text